# what the benefit of using dispatch_sync ? ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Is there a difference between these two implementation :

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
                __block UIImage *image = nil;
                dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{ 
                /* Download the image here sync downloading */
                });

                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                /* Show the image to the user here on the main queue */
                });
});
```

and

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
                __block UIImage *image = nil;
                /* Download the image here sync downloading */
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                /* Show the image to the user here on the main queue */
                });
});
```

In the first code, I download the image using a block by dispatch sync, and in the second one I download it without block!

I think I should get deadlock in the first implementation because Apple says: dispatch_sync->Calling this function and targeting the current queue results in deadlock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I should get deadlock in the first implementation because apple say :dispatch_sync->Calling this function and targeting the current queue results in deadlock

It's true if the queue is a serial queue. However, in this case, you are using global queue, thus deadlock never happen. So the difference is which thread will do `Download the image here sync downloading` in the global queue thread pool.

**First implementation**

```
main queue -----------+---------------------------------+-----------+------
         async(global)|                                 ^           |
                      v                       sync(main)|           v
global queue thread1  +-----+BLOCKED        +-----------+BLOCKED    +------
                sync(global)|               ^
                            v               |
global queue thread2        +---------------+
```

**Second implementation**

```
main queue -----------+---------------------------------+-----------+------
         async(global)|                                 ^           |
                      v                       sync(main)|           v
global queue thread1  +---------------------------------+BLOCKED    +------
```

But dispatch_sync is not good idea in this case. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

> Important: You should never call the dispatch_sync or dispatch_sync_f function from a task that is executing in the same queue that you are planning to pass to the function. This is particularly important for serial queues, which are guaranteed to deadlock, but should also be avoided for concurrent queues.

... Even though I can't find any evidence of `dispatch_sync should also be avoided for concurrent queues` from 
http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-339.92.1/src/queue.c

Comment: Presumably you should avoid it in concurrent queues for two reasons: (1) it ties up another thread, which is wasteful, and (2) if GCD is already using the maximum number of threads it's willing to spawn, you will be needlessly delayed and may deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

dispatch_sync dispatch_get_main_queue() done the action immediately.Because we are doing the cation in main queue.Here we are doing the UI updates and all that stuffs in lazy loading and asynchronous download etc.

Its related to GCD for more details please refer AppleDevelopers forum.

The main benefits of using dispatch_sync is we can do the operation concurrently.

Comment: thank you for your response ? but I don't understand how the first code work perfect, because apple said "dispatch_sync: Calling this function and targeting the current queue results in deadlock" and i do that in the first implementation

Comment: dispatch_sync make deadlock in the scenario while we are create create dispatch_sync object and try to do operation on that.It will try to do the all action in main thread.then it will became a deadlock.Because all the action try to perform in main thread.